# How to sort the object array in descending order using javascript

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Here am using amcharts API to draw the pie chart,it is working fine but according to my data there are more than 2000 criteria(more than 2000 partitions in the pie chart).. Displaying that many partitions is irrelevant.. So here i want to display only the top 10 partitions

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>amCharts: Javascript only strategy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/amstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">           
        AmCharts.ready(function() {
            loadJavascriptChartA("chartdivA", "language.txt");
        });
        // this method creates a javascript chart ploting data from external file
        function loadJavascriptChartA(elementId, file) {
            var chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
            // first we load the external data file
            var data = loadFile(file);                             
            // then we set a data provider to the chart
            chart.dataProvider = createDataProvider(data); 
            legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
            legend.align = "center";
            legend.markerType = "circle";
            chart.addTitle("Language Code/Tweets", 16);
            chart.addLegend(legend);                
            chart.titleField = "language";
            chart.valueField = "tweets";             
            chart.innerRadius = 10;
            chart.labelRadius = 1;
            chart.sequencedAnimation = true;
            chart.labelText = "[[title]]: [[value]]";
            chart.write(elementId); 
        // method which parses csv data
        function createDataProvider(data){
                    var rows = data.split("\n");
                    // create array which will hold our data:
                    dataProvider = [];
                    var start = "Tue 19 Jun 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
                    var end = "Fri 19 Jun 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
                    start = start.split(" ");
                    end = end.split(" ");
                    var starttime = start[1].concat(" ",start[2]," ",start[3]);
                    var endtime = end[1].concat(" ",end[2]," ",end[3]);
                    var bool = false;
                    var startline = 0;
                    var endline = 0;
                    var counter = 0;
            // loop through all rows
            for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++){
                        if (rows[i]) {                 
                            // our columns are separated by a semicolon
                            var column = rows[i].split(","); 
                            // column is array now
                            var date = column[0];
                            date = date.split(" ");
                            var day = date[0].concat(" ",date[1]," ",date[2]);
                        }
                        if(starttime.match(day) && bool!=true)
                        {
                            bool = true;
                            startline = i+1;
                        }
                        if(endtime.match(day)){
                            endline = i+1;
                        }
            }
            for (var j = startline-1; j < endline; j++){
                // this line helps to skip empty rows
                    // our columns are separated by a semicolon
                    var column = rows[j].split(","); 
                    // column is array now
                    var date = column[0];
                    date = date.split(" ");
                    var day = date[0].concat(" ",date[1]," ",date[2]);
                    var language  = column[1];
                    var tweets = parseInt(column[2]);
                            // check if category already exists
                            var catExists = false;
                                for (var x = 0; x < dataProvider.length; x++) {
                                    if (dataProvider[x].language == language) {
                                        catExists = true;
                                        dataProvider[x].tweets += tweets;
                                    }
                                }
                                function sortDescending(data_A, data_B)
                                {
                                    return (data_B.tweets - data_A.tweets);
                                }
                                var temp = dataProvider.sort(sortDescending);
                                if (!catExists) {
                                    // create object which contains all these items:
                                    var dataObject = {"language":language, "tweets":tweets};
                                    if(counter < 5){
                                    // add object to dataProvider array 
                                    temp.push(dataObject);
                                    counter++;
                                    }
                                }   
            }
            return dataProvider;     
        }
    }
        // method which loads external data
        function loadFile(file) {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            // load
            request.open('GET', file, false);
            request.send();
            // now lets load data into a new flash chart
            var data = request.responseText;
            //replace UNIX new line
            data = data.replace (/\r\n/g, "\n");
            //replace MAC new lines
            data = data.replace (/\r/g, "\n");
            return data;
        }

    </script>
</head>
```

```
</body>
<!--script type="text/javascript"> 
    alert(document.getElementsByName('startDateField3.value'))
</script-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
    return b - a;
}

numberArray.sort(compareNumbers);
```

Comment: here it is not just a simple array It is an object array with the values {[en,12],[te,25],..............}

Comment: @RaviTeja—that isn't valid javscript. You may either have an array arrays: `[[en,12],[te,25],...]` or an object with named properties: `{en:12, te:25, ...}`. Which is it?

Comment: Rob,sorry ya my array would be like as you mentioned {en:12, te:25, ...}